# What are the other timer APIs in Linux apart from POSIX timers?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I want to design a timer in Linux, but due to some system constraints and design requirements i cannot use the POSIX timer APIs.

Can somebody kindly let me know, what are the other timer design mechanisms available in Linux apart from the POSIX timers? (timer_create, timer_settime etc to avoid)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: P.S: Any mechanism you provide, requesting you to kindly give me some useful links or example links**

**NOTE: We can't use any third party library (Like ACE library) as our code is a proprietory code.**

Comment: You **can** use third party libs in proprietary software as long as their license allows it. For example, with lots of the permissive (**not** GPL) Open Source licenses, embedding it in binary-only commercial software is allowed.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Our bosses are skeptical :), what if the license changes tomorrow then who will change all these code?

Comment: Then you can keep using the code you have. The license cannot be changed retroactively - it could only affect future versions. Besides that, in such a case it would be very likely that someone created a fork that stays open source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817016/ways-of-implementing-timer-in-worker-thread-in-c/4820632#4820632). One of the timers I find useful is [timerfd_create()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) API provided in Linux system call. This blends well when your application is structured on an event loop.

Comment: @Manish: Thanks, let me check it and shortly get back to you in a couple of mins :)

Comment: @Manish: Thanks, i think you got me towards a good path. But why, man pages are not showing timerfd_create?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: I am able to get it. Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: @Manish: ok, anyways let me try it out from some examples. Thank you. Let me see what others reply, if not will accept your post.

Comment: @Manish timerfd_create is a rather new invention, it's possible your Linux is too old. Or you just havn't installed the proper man pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for 3rd party, there is an ACE library that can be downloaded for free. They have timers, queues, threads etc

Comment: Are there no other POSIX timer or any other specification of timer APIs? Wanted to avoid 3rd party libs.

Comment: I'm not sure... Apart from timer_create etc I don't know about any other POSIX timers.

Comment: @Mayank: Can you give me any related links for timer design using the ACE library?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/php/tjuerges/ALMA/ACE-5.5.2/html/ace/classACE__Event__Handler.html#a8) out

Comment: I found an example [here](http://huihoo.org/ace_tao/ACE-5.2+TAO-1.2/ACE_wrappers/docs/tutorials/Chap_5/ex03.html)

Comment: @Mayank: Thanks a lot, it is really helpful. But we work on ARM, i doubt wether it will work for ARM or not.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. But in our organisation we used it because it is platform independent. Its wrapper over C. We used to write ACE_OS::atoi instead of standard api call atoi. This all make me think that it should work in any C++ compiler. But still, please make sure from your side too. I worked only in intels/sparcs

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most portable way is probably just to use `pthread_create` and `clock_nanosleep` to implement your own timer. It shouldn't take more than about 50 lines of code for something simple, and maybe 100-150 for a fully general API with overrun counts, etc.

Comment: Problem is, it would have done good for monolithic kernel with no other threads running :). But in a multi-threaded environment with thousands of other threads running in parallel, there is always a chance that my `threaded timer` does not expire in real time, due to some other high priority threads. Also, if i increase the priority and use SCHED_FIFO etc (just to make sure) that no other threads can take the CPU while my thread runs, then other program's thread linked to my tool, does not get a chance to run itself before my timer expires.So it is not a feasible way what you suggest :(

Comment: Unless you've measured cpu time on your hardware and determined the timer handler will always have a plenty time, you have to be prepared for overruns; as long as they're reported you're in pretty good shape. The rest of the issues you can make part of the API. Each timer can have a priority when it's created, which gets assigned as the priority of the timer thread.

Comment: @R: One thing is evident, every timer has some overruns, even if i use the inbuilt POSIX, so i guess no timer expires in real time :(

Comment: If your process has realtime scheduling with maximum priority and the thread the timer runs in (or gets delivered to) is not performing any operations which could block/sleep (like filesystem or network access), and your cpu is sufficiently fast for the task you're performing, then it should be possible to have a timer without overruns. But on modern cpus you still have to worry about things like different power states, etc. If you can find a way to keep track of and handle overruns, it's much more robust to do it that way.

Comment: yes, but ours is an ARM CPU, and our userland (distribution) is also developed by us, and finally the CE-Linux, which runs on devices with thousands of apps, so although i agree to your statement, but such condition is ideally hard to achieve.